# google maps api: how to disable commercial locations?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've created a custom map using the APIv3 and I've positioned my markers (hotel and restaurants addresses)

But in the map there are also, by default, some labels of hotels, restaurants, and any kind of commercial location. And some of them are in competition with my customers...

Is there a way to remove them from the map, leaving in the map's view only non-commercial names?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can disable these advertisements by styledmaptype.

> If you would prefer that your Maps API application not include these
>   icons, you can remove them ahead of next week’s release by setting
>   visibility:off on the labels element of poi.business for your map.

See : http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.com/2011/08/business-icons-and-styling-across.html

But remember, these labels are also hidden when you specify "visibility:off" for poi.business.

Otherwise, you can disable these advertisements if you contract with Google Maps API for Business license.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just for screenshots:

If you have the menu on the left you can try and disable "labels".

You can also right click on most elements (thought not the businesses) and inspect, then scroll up and down till you see "scene" and bring the z-index to 9999 and it will hide all navagation buttons. This will bring the map over everything except the "google" logo at the bottom.

I wouldn't mind leaving the Copyright info there but haven't figured that out yet.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you need to toggle the visibility of poi.business labels, like this:

```
{
  featureType: 'poi.business',
  elementType: 'labels',
  stylers: [
    { visibility: 'off' }
  ]
}
```