# How to hide commercial locations on Google Map iOS SDK

Tags: javascript, android, ios, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using Google Maps SDK for iOS to develop an based-map app. Map also shows many commercial locations like hotels, restaurants, companies,... It's bad for my app in some cases so I want to hide them, just show some information such as street name, parks name or some general places name.

I got the topic that handled the problem but in Javascript

[google maps api: how to disable commercial locations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035725/google-maps-api-how-to-disable-commercial-locations)

There was another topic said that changing map type is a acceptable option

[How to hide default labels on Google Maps iOS SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24431602/how-to-hide-default-labels-on-google-maps-ios-sdk)

but there is no mapType suit for me, I want a normal type map.

Is there any solution for this using Google Map api on iOS

Answer (score 0):

You can give mapTypeId.ROADMAP a try. It's one of the simplest map UIs. It doesn't show the commercial locations you're so trying to avoid.

```
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 8,
center: myLatlng,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```

Read [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#MapTypes) to browse more about simple maps.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, but it seems on Javascript, not available type RoadMap on GoogleMaps.framework on iOS yet, I suppose